# Plotly, scroll through two array slices with one slider

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to scroll through two same-sized image/arrays using the same slider.

I know how to scroll through one array at a time:

```
fig = px.imshow(masks, animation_frame=0, binary_string=True, labels=dict(animation_frame="Slice"))
fig.show()
```

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoCe8.png)

And how to plot two slices side by side.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    horizontal_spacing=0.1, 
                    shared_yaxes=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=masks[10], colorscale='Gray'), 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=rois[10], colorscale='Gray'), 1, 2)
fig.show()
```

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv1Q6.png)

But I don't understand how can I scroll through both of them, displayed side by side, using the same slider.

Comment: I find [this answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/using-one-slider-to-control-multiple-subplots-not-multiple-traces/13955/3) to be very helpful